# Android App with Google Drive API stucks after choosing an account. Why?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-drive-api

I'm trying to understand how I can integrate Google Drive API in my Android App(using Android Studio). I have tried the example app that I found here(https://github.com/googleworkspace/android-samples/tree/master/drive/deprecation) but after Google API console configuration my app stucks in an infinite loop when I choose an Account. Why? Where is the problem?
I tried also with this(https://youtu.be/5bSEIQYJzKs) tutorial but I have the same problem.
Here my build.gradle specific lines:

```
implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1"
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:19.0.0'
implementation ('com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v3-rev136-1.25.0')
            {
                exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
            }
implementation ('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.26.0')
            {
                exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
            }
implementation 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.26.0'
```

and here is the version that I use

```
compileSdkVersion 30
buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"
```

The problem is in this code lines, and occurs only if I use ".requestScopes(new Scope(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE))":
if i donot use .requestScopes(new Scope(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE))", then code works fine. and user do get logedin

```
GoogleSignInOptions signInOptions = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestScopes(new Scope(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
GoogleSignInClient client= GoogleSignIn.getClient(this,signInOptions);
Intent i= client.getSignInIntent();
startActivityForResult(i,400);
```

(it seems like the activity never returns any value).
Without ".requestScopes(new Scope(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE))" the auth request is successful.
Here my Google console configuration:
[The client ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHTaR.png)
(sorry, maybe it will appear as a link but stackOverflow tell me that I can't put img)
and
".../auth/drive.file" is the authorization that I request in google Consent window that appears to the user.
I don't know if it is important to say but I use a real phone and not the Android Studio emulator to test my app.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just solved it. For all those who encounter this problem: from the Google API console, remove the consent screen from the test state and publish it.

Comment: To clarify here for anyone else reading, changing the OAuth consent publishing mode from "Testing" to "Production" (click "Confirm" on the dialog if it's asking you about verification) and this seems to work for now. It's clear there still something broken on Google's end when OAuth is set to "Testing" mode.

Comment: It seems Google has fixed the problem, and now the old solution appears to be the problem. Putting app back into Testing now fixed the hanging problem which returned in two of my apps that I had flipped to Production to fix the problem months ago.

Comment: Seeing the same behavior on an app we built just months ago which uses the Gmail APIs with read-only scope. Everything was working fine until a few weeks back. Login works for the testers when on "Testing" mode as expected but when flipped to "Production", only works for the dev account used to create the project. For the other accounts, it never goes to the consent screen after choosing the account and shows loading indefinitely.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/178183308 where the issue was reported to Google.

Comment: thank you very much. This is very helpful. I was looking for that but I did not find it at all. I have just voted your answer as useful but SO don't display it because of my reputation(I am new in this platform). I hope you can see my vote. I'll check it as soon as my reputation increase.

Comment: Glad to see an issue has been filed for this, took me a few days to realize this probably wasn't my fault.