# Google fit stuck in loading after selecting account

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, google-fit

I'm developing google fit integration in an android app.
I developed reading and writing blood pressure and fitness activity data in google fit. It works fine before the recent google policies, then we found the app should be verified to access the user's data. We have done the whole process of verification and received permission to read/write blood pressure and fitness activity.
[image]

But after all the process, the sign-in process and consent page works fine with activity fit Apis and Write blood pressure Api, but once I add Read Blood pressure Api, the consent page is stuck in indefinite loading without any error. It happens suddenly after updating the google fit library and finishing the verification process.

[image]

Here is the fitness options code:

```
val fitnessOptions = FitnessOptions.builder()
 .accessActivitySessions(FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ)
 .accessActivitySessions(FitnessOptions.ACCESS_WRITE)
 //some other permissions for fitness activity
 .addDataType(HealthDataTypes.TYPE_BLOOD_PRESSURE, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_WRITE)
 .addDataType(HealthDataTypes.TYPE_BLOOD_PRESSURE, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ)
.build()
```

And the sign-in function in the activty is:

```
GoogleSignIn.requestPermissions(
                this,
                requestCode,
                GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(requireContext()),fitnessOptions)
```

The gradle file related to version:

```
    googleImplementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:20.0.0"
    googleImplementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:19.2.0"
```

I'm wondering why it's not working in only one of the apis!
Could someone help me?

Comment: It seems to be an issue on the Google side not the SDK itself. Could you try solution mentioned on this post? If you can see any error on the Logcat you may also share it as well.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68975985/3057100