# Google OAuth stuck on loading screen in production

Tags: android, oauth-2.0

Using OAuth sign in for an app and it's getting stuck during the loading screen as seen below. The status has been changed to 'in production' as you can see, and no verification is needed according to google. It does say however my app has not been reviewed, does my app need to be put on the play store having been reviewed for this to work? Currently it's only on internal testing track and yet to be published. Any help on this is much appreciated.

Just to note this works fine when app is in testing status.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google OAuth sign-in stuck loading consent screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65974714/google-oauth-sign-in-stuck-loading-consent-screen)

Comment: Kindly provide what you have tried, and without code we cant see what's wrong in your app

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Have you added ````<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION" />```` in your manifest?

Comment: Yes that's there, just to note it all works fine if the app is in the testing status