# Google SignIn error getToken() -> NEED_REMOTE_CONSENT

Tags: android, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, google-api

Few month ego, my google signIn procedure works without problem, but today the emulator reply me in the Logcat this error:

**E/Auth: [GoogleAccountDataServiceImpl] getToken() -> NEED_REMOTE_CONSENT. App: com_pro.bandweb.mycpstore, Service: oauth2:email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly openid profile**

try to look in google but I not find any suggestion...this are the code that I use for sigIn:

```
public void InitGoogle() throws IOException {
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestScopes(new Scope(SPREADSHEETS_SCOPE))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
        googleSignInClient = com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);

        if (GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this) == null) {
            Log.v(TAG, "getting sign-on again");
            //startActivityForResult(googleSignInClient.getSignInIntent(), RC_SIGN_IN);
            SignInActivityResult.launch(googleSignInClient.getSignInIntent());
        } else {
            Log.v(TAG, "sign-on is still good, reusing");

            //faccio la richiesta solo se è stato inserito il foglio di google shhet nelle preferenze, altrimenti avviso
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            if (!sharedPreferences.contains(getString(R.string.pref_googleSheetId_key))
                    || StringUtils.isBlank(sharedPreferences.getString(getString(R.string.pref_googleSheetId_key), ""))
                    || !(spreadsheetIdPattern.matcher(sharedPreferences.getString(getString(R.string.pref_googleSheetId_key), ""))).find()) {
                // no Google sheet ID has been specified - can't retrieve ingredients
                progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
                Toasty.info(this, getString(R.string.missing_pref_id_sheet_title), Toasty.LENGTH_LONG, true).show();
            }else {
                //scelgo il tipo di sincronizzazione quando inizializzo il tablet, in base alla scelta nelle preferenze
                if(AppSettings.get().getSyncModeOnStartup() == UPLOAD_DATI)
                    synchGoogleSheet(UPLOAD_DATI);
                else if(AppSettings.get().getSyncModeOnStartup() == DOWNLOAD_DATI)
                    synchGoogleSheet(DOWNLOAD_DATI);
                else
                    synchGoogleSheet(UPLOAD_DOWNLOAD_NONE);
            }
        }
        progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);

..
..
..
..





ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> SignInActivityResult= registerForActivityResult(
        new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
        new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                if(result.getResultCode() != RESULT_CANCELED) {
                    if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK && null != result.getData())
                    {
                        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(result.getData());
                        handleSignInResult(task);
                    }
                }else{
                    progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: did you get any solution?

Comment: no Unfortunately...

Comment: It was working fine last week.

Comment: Hi @AndyBand any luck with this? Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you do all steps below:

- Setup Google cloud console like @[Tomáš Hubálek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/150359/tom%C3%A1%C5%A1-hub%C3%A1lek) said above, with correct SHA1 key (Note about [Google App signing key](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#app-signing-google-play) from PlayStore console if your app was published).

In my case, after a lot of solutions without working. I found and used this solution for only `UserRecoverableAuthIOException` error, and it work.

Java version

```java
catch (UserRecoverableAuthIOException userRecoverableException) {
   myActivity.startActivityForResult(
   userRecoverableException.getIntent(), MyActivity.REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);
}
```

Kotlin version

```
catch (e: Exception) {
   if (e is UserRecoverableAuthIOException) {
   myActivity.startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), MyActivity.REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);
   } else {
      // other cases
   }
}
```

Comment: Is there any scenario (maybe perhaps with production/public users) that this could get stuck in some infinite loop where the user would keep getting sent to the auth screen?

Comment: If i'm not wrong, on  receiving google User Recoverable Auth Exception we need to go for authenticate user again, and if we try to do that, then it'll go to the infinite loop of authentication process.

Comment: You guys my catch the retry action. In additional, try to logs if the exception (to firebase) is appeared in loop.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on a Google Pixel 5 with Android 11.

```
2021-08-11 13:32:59.603 29917-30363/? E/Auth: [GoogleAccountDataServiceImpl] getToken() -> NEED_REMOTE_CONSENT. App: de.aoksystems.ma.abp.app.internal, Service: oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.activity.read https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.heart_rate.read https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.nutrition.read
```

But it works fine on a Samsung S10 with Android 11

4 Weeks ago it works.

Comment: same issue on pixel 6 / Android 12

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Google Drive API. I was requesting DRIVE_FILE and DRIVE scopes. I deleted requesting DRIVE scope permission and the problem disappeared. I'm pretty sure the problem is encountered by developers, who doesn't have necessary permissions in Google API Console. So, you should check your permissions there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing the same error, and for me it's looking like it's related to my Google account.

My app uses the Google Drive API, and I haven't touched the code since 2016. I don't use the app that often, but at some point in the past year the drive integration stopped working for me on my old phone which was running Android 8. I've just switched to a new phone running Android 11, and get the same error on that. However, one other person is using my app and they have no issues at all (also Android 11).

In the security section of my Google account my app used to appear as having third-party access, however that's now disappeared and I know I wouldn't have revoked it myself. For the other user of my app it's still present in their account.

**Update**: I've managed to resolve this, without actually making any code changes to the app. I set up an emulator (Pixel 5, Android 11) connected to my Google account, ran my app on that and it correctly displayed the consent screen instead of returning this error. After allowing that, and thus having my app now appear in my account as having third-party access, functionality of the app was immediately restored on my phone.

It doesn't sound like this solution will work for everyone, but at least in my case that error message seemed to mean my account wasn't authorised for my app, and was stuck in such a way that it needed another device/emulator to "force" it through.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29812116)

Answer (score 0):

In my app this error message was caused by missing OAuth Consent screen. To fix that you have to do following:

1. Go to Google Cloud Console
2. Select your project
3. Select APIs & Service
4. Select OAuth consent screen
5. Fill all required information

After doing that `NEED_REMOTE_CONSENT` error disappeared immediately.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, this seems it may be related to Android 12.

My app runs and authenticates fine on Android R (API30) but when I deploy the same apk on Android S (API31) I get the exact same error message:

```
E/Auth: [GoogleAccountDataServiceImpl] getToken() -> NEED_REMOTE_CONSENT.  In both cases I'm testing on the Android Emulator as well a physical devices.
```

In my case, the problem is in accessing the Google Fit and Google Tasks APIs

Answer (score -1):

You can follow this procedure by configuring the google API console:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65900011
and arriving at this intermediate [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fK7xF.jpg).