# Google Drive API: UserRecoverableAuthIOException (NeedRemoteConsent)

Tags: android, oauth, google-drive-api

#### Background

My app uses Google Drive API to create/manage files in an isolated folder using the non-sensitive scope on a user's Google Drive account after they've linked the account using the standard OAuth consent flow.

I have the following scopes enabled for my OAuth consent screen:

- ./auth/drive.appdata
- ./auth/drive.file

#### Issue

I'm observing user-reported issues where clients are unable to perform actions on their Google Drive account because of the following stack trace:

```
Non-fatal Exception: com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.UserRecoverableAuthIOException
   at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential$RequestHandler.intercept(GoogleAccountCredential.java:297)
   at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:868)
   at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:476)
   at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:409)
   at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:526)
   at com.mystuff.app.cloud.google.drive.GoogleDriveQuery.executeListQuery(GoogleDriveQuery.java:84)
   at com.mystuff.app.cloud.google.drive.GoogleDriveQuery.getList(GoogleDriveQuery.java:39)
   ...
Caused by com.google.android.gms.auth.UserRecoverableAuthException: NeedRemoteConsent
   at com.google.android.gms.auth.zze.zzb(zze.java:13)
   at com.google.android.gms.auth.zzd.zza(zzd.java:77)
   at com.google.android.gms.auth.zzd.zzb(zzd.java:20)
   at com.google.android.gms.auth.zzd.getToken(zzd.java:7)
   at com.google.android.gms.auth.zzd.getToken(zzd.java:5)
   at com.google.android.gms.auth.zzd.getToken(zzd.java:2)
   at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(GoogleAuthUtil.java:55)
   at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential.getToken(GoogleAccountCredential.java:267)
   at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential$RequestHandler.intercept(GoogleAccountCredential.java:292)
   at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:868)
   at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:476)
   at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:409)
   at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:526)
   at com.mystuff.app.cloud.google.drive.GoogleDriveQuery.executeListQuery(GoogleDriveQuery.java:84)
   ...
```

#### Code

The code that executes is this, it essentially fetches a list of all the eligible folders that my app has created:

```
private FileList executeListQuery(GoogleDriveService driveService, String q, String pageToken) {
  try {
    final Drive.Files.List query =
        driveService
            .get()
            .files()
            .list()
            .setSpaces("drive")
            .setQ(q)
            .setFields(FILE_LIST_FIELDS)
            .setOrderBy("createdTime desc");
    if (pageToken != null) {
      query.setPageToken(pageToken);
    }
    return query.execute();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

I don't think the issue is specific to this block of code but anywhere I execute queries to the Google API.

#### Question

It seems like **this issue is happening to *some* users only** even though they have consented to all the requested permissions and my API config has the correct non-sensitive scopes enabled. I'm unable to reproduce the issue on my own client but I am able to confirm through user-provided screenshots that this issue occurs even though permissions are fully granted during the consent screen.

**Does anyone know what might be causing this issue?** This issue seems to occur for certain users all the time and doesn't seem to fix itself. I'm unsure if it's account-specific.

Other context and things I've tried:

- Happens across multiple Android versions (at least from 8 to 11)
- I've attempted to revoke my own test account's Google Drive permissions but technically my app requires it and won't complete the OAuth without it
- [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69252934/394933) on SO sounds similar but my feature already works for most devices so I think my API scopes are already set up correctly

[image]

Comment: Try my answer at this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/72444736/3682565

Comment: Appreciate your comment, interesting solution. Do you know how to reproduce this issue consistently? The issue I originally observed is reported in crash logs from my app but I'm not able to actually reproduce it myself.

Comment: It's hard to reproduce, some of my users have this problem, others not. And I reproduce only 1 time by creating a new example project, setup cloud console, steps by steps. Steps are create android with google oauth (+ your scopes) => Add consent info and scopes to cloud console => add sha1 oauth creadential... Each step runs with different issue, luckily, 1 of them is `NeedRemoteConsent`, and I tried to fix it by above solution.